# Ionic Angular - Sliding Option Text Hidden

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have the following that generates a list of `ion-item-sliding` elements where the label is some text and then the buttons (will eventually) allow the user to edit/delete the current item:

```html
<ion-list *ngIf="examples | async; else loading">
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let example of examples | async">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>{{example.ExampleName}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    
    <ion-item-options>
      <ion-item-option>Edit</ion-item-option>
      <ion-item-option color="danger">Delete</ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

The issue is that if one of the items has very little text in the label, then the entire label is hidden (see image).
[image: Ionic sliding option issue]

Is there a way to make it so that the text gets hidden from right-to-left instead of from left-to-right? For example, using the screenshot above, the topmost entry would say "This is an example with a lot" and then "of text" would be cut off.

Comment: is the problem that edit and delete is on a new line ? if so you can fix it with css, give the box a max-width and overflow: hidden

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen - No, the text for the second line was "Example" but because the text was so small that it was being "pushed" off of the screen when the edit/delete buttons would become visible (via the sliding option behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a little workaround with the event (ionDrag) and getOpenAmount to apply the margin base on the slide. That need a little more work on the reset but it does the trick to avoid the label disappearing.

See the methods here : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v6/api/item-sliding#methods

**HTML**

```
 <ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding (ionDrag)="testMargin($event)" slot="end">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label id="testId">This label</ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item-options>
      <ion-item-option>Edit</ion-item-option>
      <ion-item-option color="danger">Delete</ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
  <ion-item-sliding>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>That label</ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item-options>
      <ion-item-option>Edit</ion-item-option>
      <ion-item-option color="danger">Delete</ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

**TS**

```
  testMargin(ev: any) {

    ev.target.getOpenAmount().then((el) => document.getElementById('testId').style.marginLeft = el + 'px');

  }
```